# e-signing my pdf file in ios limits my pdf content

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, digital-signature

Am trying to sign my pdf file which is multiple paged, I could fetch the signature drawn in UIView to my pdf file, but the problem i face is, after signing the pdf, i could view only the single page of file which is signed, not rest of the pages in my webview.(for eg; if page 3 of my pdf file is signed, i could view only page 3 in my webview).

Codes used for fetching the e-sign in my pdf file

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 460)];
path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typo_tips" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectoryPath;
NSURL *targetURL;
documentDirectoryPath  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"typo_tips.pdf"];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:documentDirectoryPath error:&error];

targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath];

if (entered==1)//entered assigned 1, after save button clicked in UIView
{


    CFURLRef url;
    url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath]);
    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
    myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL); 
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

    int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
    NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

   CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument,page));
    //"page" is current pdf page to be signed, which can be fetched from user during runtime the pdf file is clicked.



    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];// image is the e-sign saved in doc. directory


    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    //  CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, image.size.height);
    //   CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);

    // Clean up
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}

I could guess the cause of problem, because after the image is merged with pdf file, the single page of pdf which is got signed remains in the document directory, so that i could not display rest of pages in pdf file. Can any one help me to recover from this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not sign the original file, it creates a copy of a single page and then signs that page. This is why you see only one page.
What you can do is to copy the source file to another file (copy each page the same way you copy the current one) and then sign the page you want.